# How to remote Linux desktop with audio support

Tags: linux, audio, remote, vnc

I have a Debian PC (Server) and I would like to remote this machine from one client (Windows, Ubuntu,..) and be able to hear the sound from the server.

I tried some tools (Radmin, RealVNC, but I can't use Teamviewer because of pricing) but I can not transfer sound from server to client.

So, my question is what tool can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FreeRDP with Multimedia Redirection

> ## FreeRDP: A Remote Desktop Protocol Implementation
>
> FreeRDP is a free implementation of the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP),
>   released under the Apache license. Enjoy the freedom of using your
>   software wherever you want, the way you want it, in a world where
>   interoperability can finally liberate your computing experience.
>
> ### Resources
>
> Project website: http://www.freerdp.com/
>   Issue tracker: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues
>   Sources: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/
>   Wiki: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki
>   Downloads and other resources: http://pub.freerdp.com
>   API doc: http://pub.freerdp.com/api/
>
> IRC channel: #freerdp @ irc.freenode.net Mailing list:
>   https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/freerdp-devel
>
> ### Microsoft Open Specifications
>
> Information regarding the Microsoft Open Specifications can be found
>   at: http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/
>
> A list of reference documentation is maintained here:
>   https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Reference-Documentation
>
> ### Compilation
>
> Instructions on how to get started compiling FreeRDP can be found on
>   the wiki: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation

<sub>https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/blob/master/README</sub>

### Multimedia Redirection

https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Multimedia-Redirection

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, please show me more descriptions about `JACK`, an example?

Comment: FreeRDP's server component seems to be immature and buggy, at least for me.

Comment: The multimedia redirection link says that the server has to be Windows, not GNU/Linux

Answer (score 4):

### X2Go

Having had trouble with FreeRDP's server component, I would have tried FreeNX, since NX has been around for a while, but
[this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=47548) pointed out that CentOS 7 now ships with [X2Go](http://wiki.x2go.org) instead of NX, so I installed that on my CentOS 7 system.  When I connected from my Windows 8 machine, it worked well, with sound, except it seemed to make the remote display too large so some of it was cut off.  I haven't tried to fix this yet.

The client actually SSHes to the remote system and runs the required software, so you don't need to run anything like `vncserver` first, although I suspect that is probably another option.

Comment: Note that X2Go Server is [no longer compatible](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat) with GNOME or Unity, and possibly other desktop environments.

Answer (score 2):

[Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) is a free, web-based media streamer, providing ubiquitous access to your music. Use it to share your music with friends, or to listen to your own music while at work. You can stream to multiple players simultaneously, for instance to one player in your kitchen and another in your living room.

Alternatively, you could consider [streaming MPD with Icecast](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Streaming_With_Icecast).

[Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) is a program for streaming audio such as music across a network. Different types of clients connect to the IceCast server, either to provide a "mount point", control the server, or listen to the audio being cast.

[MPD](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) is a program for playing music via a daemon process instead of using a client. It also incorporates a music database for quick access, playlists, and a variety of front-end options.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **Cendio ThinLinc** would solve your need.
It has audio support through PulseAudio.
It is based on open source (TigerVNC and others).
You can use it for free up to 5 users. : )

[www.cendio.com](http://www.cendio.com)