# Sound doesn't work on a Centos 6.5 VPS

Tags: audio

I installed GNOME Desktop Environment on Centos 6 on my VPS, then I installed Firefox, Flashplayer and VLC. Everything work well but I can't hear the sound. I searched for a solution on the Internet but couldn't find.

Here are 3 screenshots for the system, the sound output and the sound card after running 'alsamixer' from the terminal.

[image: firefox]

[image: sound preferences]

[image: alsamixer]

Answer (score 0):

Your server only has a “Dummy Output” for sound, so it's normal that you don't hear anything. (That's [dummy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dummy) in the sense of “a deliberately nonfunctional device or tool used in place of a functional one”, it's a coincidence that it happens to match the “mute” meaning of dummy.)

If this was a physical server rather than a VPS, you would be attempting to play a sound through the server's loudspeakers (you wouldn't normally have the permission to do so when you aren't using the console though). VNC doesn't forward sound, only keyboard/mouse input and windowed display.

You'll need to set up sound forwarding separately. See

- [How to remote Linux desktop with audio support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116621/how-to-remote-linux-desktop-with-audio-support)
- [How can I forward sound over VNC?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138350/how-can-i-forward-sound-over-vnc)
- [Sending audio through network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1893/sending-audio-through-network)
- [Linux newbie: How do I use Jack? How does Linux sound work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76638/linux-newbie-how-do-i-use-jack-how-does-linux-sound-work)